# Unable to add physical volume to volume group LVM

Tags: linux, lvm

Can you help me fix the problem add more GB to vg?

Please look. I explain my problem:

```
[root@jdk ~]# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
vda         252:0    0   900G  0 disk
├─vda1      252:1    0   512M  0 part /boot
└─vda2      252:2    0 899,5G  0 part
  ├─vg-root 253:0    0 697,5G  0 lvm  /
  └─vg-swap 253:1    0     2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
loop0         7:0    0     4G  0 loop /var/tmp
```

```
[root@jdk ~]# vgextend vg /dev/vda2
  Physical volume '/dev/vda2' is already in volume group 'vg'
  Unable to add physical volume '/dev/vda2' to volume group 'vg'
  /dev/vda2: physical volume not initialized.
```

```
[root@jdk ~]# vgs
  VG #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree
  vg   1   2   0 wz--n- <699,50g    0
```

@JatinMehrotra  I added pvdisplay: Please check

```
[root@jdk ~]# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/vda2
  VG Name               vg
  PV Size               <699,50 GiB / not usable 2,00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              179071
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          179071
  PV UUID               EfPZuZ-gQ0R-nFLD-pnwm-DS16-IAXf-ikO5RM
```

Comment: can you post the output of pvdisplay command or pvs command

Comment: @JatinMehrotra  

I added on the top

Answer (score 3):

Accodring to LVM, `/dev/vda2` is already in volume group `vg` and all of its space is already being used for volume group. However, the physical volume is only ~700 GB in size while the partition `/dev/vda2` is ~900 GB, so it looks as if ~200 GB of partition is not being used for physical volume.

This could happen for example if you created physical volume with explicit size parameter, or if you enlarged your partition after PV has already been created on it.

In such case, `pvresize` should be able to add the missing space. After that, you should see a higher `Total PE` and also some `Free PE` in the output of `pvdisplay`. Then you can use this space to extend existing logical volumes with `lvextend`, or to create new logical volumes with `lvcreate`.

And just to mention, if you will enlarge `vg-root` or `vg-swap`, you will also need to resize the filesystem it contains.